# Specifying a custom DateTime format when serializing with Json.Net

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am developing an API to expose some data using ASP.NET Web API.

In one of the API, the client wants us to expose the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I don't want to change the global settings (e.g. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter`) for that since it is very specific to this client. And I do developing that in a solution for multiple clients.

One of the solution that I could think of is to create a custom `JsonConverter` and then put that to the property I need to do the custom formatting

e.g.

```
class ReturnObjectA 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get;set;}
}
```

Just wondering if there is some other easy way of doing that.

Comment: For what it's worth, APIs are for computer readability, not user readability, so it's better to stick to a single specified date format, such as [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/).  If the client is directly displaying the API result to the user, or writing their own date parsing code for the API, then they're doing it wrong.  Formatting a date for display should be left to the topmost UI layer.

Comment: Create web API by using Visual Studio 2019, fixed by [Formatting DateTime in ASP.NET Core 3.0 using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102189/formatting-datetime-in-asp-net-core-3-0-using-system-text-json)

Comment: I steer clear of sprinkling Json.NET specifics into my DTOs.  Instead, I have DTO date properties you mention as `string`s that are formatted with a shared `const string` value.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Since you said you can't modify the global settings, then the next best thing is to apply the `JsonConverter` attribute on an as-needed basis, as you suggested.  It turns out Json.Net already has a built-in [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) that lets you specify the date format.  Unfortunately, you can't set the format via the `JsonConverter` attribute, since the attribute's sole argument is a type.  However, there is a simple solution: subclass the `IsoDateTimeConverter`, then specify the date format in the constructor of the subclass.  Apply the `JsonConverter` attribute where needed, specifying your custom converter, and you're ready to go.  Here is the entirety of the code needed:

```
class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

If you don't mind having the time in there also, you don't even need to subclass the IsoDateTimeConverter. Its default date format is `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK` (as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs)).

Comment: @Koen Zomers - The single quotes you removed from my date formats technically ARE correct, although they are not strictly necessary here.  See _Literal String Delimiters_ in the [documentation for Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).  However, the format I quoted as the default format for the `IsonDateTimeConverter` was taken directly from the [Json.Net source code](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs); therefore I am reverting your edit on that.

Comment: it didn't work here with the quotes and it did without them, but if you say it should, I probably did something wrong. Sorry for the edit.

Answer (score 176):

You could use this approach:

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
class ReturnObjectA 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get;set;}
}
```

The `DateTimeFormat` string uses the .NET format string syntax described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get `'JsonConverterAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`

Comment: This is the most flexible solution. If you get the following error : `'JsonConverterAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`, it means your version of json.net is too old. You need to update to the latest json.net version.

Comment: Works for me. Any idea how I can remove the time? So only return 2020-02-12 for example with the T00:00:00

Comment: @Enrico Simple: `[JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-dd\"T:00:00:00\"")]`

Comment: @TamCoton one of the reasons seeing this error might be that you are referencing "System.Text.Json` instead of ."Newtonsoft.Json" in your file. At least that was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 74):

It can also be done with an `IsoDateTimeConverter` instance, without changing global formatting settings:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject,
    new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" });
```

This uses the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` overload that takes a `params JsonConverter[]` argument.

Comment: If you are serializing same class object in many places, then accepted answer is better than this

Answer (score 26):

Also available using one of the serializer settings overloads:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ" });
```

Or

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ" });
```

Overloads taking a Type are also available.

Comment: FYI I think you mean `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` .. 24 hour clock on the hours.

Answer (score 13):

There is another solution I've been using. Just create a string property and use it for json. This property wil return date properly formatted.

```
class JSonModel {
    ...

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string CustomDate {
        get { return MyDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy"); }
        // set { MyDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        set { MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddMMyyyy", null); }
    }

    ...
}
```

This way you don't have to create extra classes. Also, it allows you to create diferent data formats. e.g, you can easily create another Property for Hour using the same DateTime.

Answer (score 10):

With below converter

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        public CustomDateTimeConverter()
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        }

        public CustomDateTimeConverter(string format)
        {
            DateTimeFormat = format;
        }
    }
```

Can use it with a default custom format

```
class ReturnObjectA 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get;set;}
}
```

Or any specified format for a property

```
class ReturnObjectB 
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter), "dd MMM yy")]
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializer { get; set; } = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatString= "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver()
        };
```

Hello,

I'm using this property when I need set JsonSerializerSettings

Answer (score 0):

Some times decorating the json convert attribute will not work ,it will through exception saying that "***2010-10-01" is valid date***. To avoid this types i removed json convert attribute on the property and mentioned in the deserilizedObject method like below.

```
var addresss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressHistory>(address, new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
```