# JSON.NET converter CanConvert - how to access attributes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We need to write a custom `JsonConverter` for `DateTime` and `DateTime?` in order to respect the date format specified with the `DisplayFormat` attribute.

[if anybody knows of an existing converter doing exactly this -> we would like to know of it :-)]

We derived our converter from `JsonConverter`, however, there seems to be no way to access any attributes as we do not have access to the property being converted - only to its type and value.

Is there any other way we overlooked? How to access attributes from within a JsonConverter?

Comment: Will all of your dates have the same display format, or does it vary?

Comment: Varies, some will show the date only, some are going to show date and time. Otherwise we would have replaced the default serialization behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, there does not seem to be a way to access, from within a converter, the context (parent object) for the object being converted.  Another answer (now deleted) claimed that you could by way of the `Context` property on the `JsonSerializer`, but this returns a `StreamingContext` which does not contain information about the parent object (its inner `Context` property is always null in my testing).

Perhaps a possible solution for your situation is to use a variation of the idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639829/10263).  In other words, create custom derivatives of the `IsoDateTimeConverter`, one for each different date format that you require.  I'm guessing there will only be a small number of these needed.  Then, decorate your `DateTime` properties with the `[JsonConverter]` attribute, specifying which custom date converter to use for each property based on the date format needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the parent object in the StreamingContext.Context which is a place holder for extra information in [OnSerializing callback](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) of the parent object. I suggest defining this context as a dictionary of string and object and with predefined keys. In the converter then you can get the stored additional information from Serializer.Context.