# modify linq query to turn field from datetime to string

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api2

So I have a linq expression that that selects a group of records between a certain datetime, as chosen by the user. However, after the callDate is used as a datetime type I need it turned into a string before it is output

**Current Code:**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Detail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetail(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
    DateTime EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);

    var detail = from a in db.Details where (a.callDate >= StartDate && a.callDate <= EndDate) select a
```

**Model:**

```
[Required]
public DateTime callDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CallDate to be returned as a string, you need to select your results as a new object type. This can either be a class you have created, or an anonymous type, or just the date. Examples:

```
//class
IEnumerable<MyConvertedClass> details = db.Details.Where(a => a.callDate >= StartDate && a.callDate <= EndDate)
                                                  .ToList().Select(a => new MyConvertedClass { Id = a.Id, CallDate = a.CallDate.ToShortDateString() });

//where MyConvertedClass looks like this: 
public class MyConvertedClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CallDate { get; set; }
}

//just the dates
IEnumerable<DateTime> details = from a in db.Details where (a.callDate >= StartDate && a.callDate <= EndDate) 
                                select a.CallDate;

//anonymous type
var detail = from a in db.Details where (a.callDate >= StartDate && a.callDate <= EndDate) 
             select new { Id = a.Id, CallDate = a.CallDate.ToShortDateString() };
```

If you are using the anonymous type in the same block it's fine, or returning it from your API, but maybe don't return it from a method to be used elsewhere. It's hard to deal with anonymous types. (http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/)

**EDIT:**
Okay, so it looks like you are returning the Detail model from your api controller. In this case, you can't change the type of CallDate (unless you create a new class as above), but you can control the format that the Date is serialized in (default is ISO 8601 [`2009-02-15T00:00:00Z`]. Check this stackoverflow question to see how to set up a custom formatter to output the date in a particular format:

[Specifying a custom DateTime format when serializing with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: I'm attempting to use the class one but on the callDate I get an error of `Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Date.Time`

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy , to confirm, what types are StartDate and EndDate, and what type is CallDate on your Details class and your converted class?

Comment: Updated my question hopefully it helps. Also I don't think I understand what you mean by converted class, I'm attempting your example with my Model class

Comment: Ok, so I've made a converted class and no build errors but when I try to run it I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method`

Comment: K. Updated. Added a tolist so the SQL will execute before it does the string conversion.

Comment: It worked! I have so much to learn about linq, thank you for the knowledge.