# Custom json serialization for each item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.NET to serialize an object that has an `IEnumerable` of an enum and `DateTime`. It's something like:

```
class Chart
{
    // ...
    public IEnumerable<int> YAxis { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<State> Data { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> XAxis { get; set; }
}
```

But I need a custom `JsonConverter` to make the enum serialize as string and to change the `DateTime` string format.

I've tried using the `JsonConverter` attribute as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639829/3036440) for enum and a custom `IsoDateTimeConverter` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public IEnumerable<State> Data { get; set; }

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
public IEnumerable<DateTime> XAxis { get; set; }
```

I was hoping it would work for an `IEnumerable` too, but unsurprisingly it doesn't:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Int32,Model.State]' to type 'System.Enum'.

Is there any way to say that the `JsonConverterAttribute` applies to each item and not on the enumerable itself?

Comment: @juharr This was actually an effort to share something that got in my way. And to think I was proud of my googling skills...

Answer (score 10):

Turns out that for enumerables you have to use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) and the [`ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) property as follows:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public IEnumerable<State> Data { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
public IEnumerable<DateTime> XAxis { get; set; }
```

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm) as:

> To apply a JsonConverter to the items in a collection, use either JsonArrayAttribute, JsonDictionaryAttribute or JsonPropertyAttribute and set the ItemConverterType property to the converter type you want to use.

You might be confused with `JsonArrayAttribute`, but it
 cannot target a property.