# Anyone know how to format a list of dates using JsonConverter attribute

Tags: c#, json, datetime

Here is a similar issue, but it didn't get any answers. [How to format a list of dates using JsonConverter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911846/how-to-format-a-list-of-dates-using-jsonconverter-attribute)

Here is the question:
I try to use a JsonConverter attribute using a custom IsoDateTimeConverter on the DateTime fields that need to be formatted as `ISO date time format`

```
public class DateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}


public class A
{

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]
    public List<DateTime> Example { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> Unexpected value when converting date. Expected DateTime or DateTimeOffset, got System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime].

I checked all the documents from https://www.newtonsoft.com, but I can't find anything relate to this issue.

Please give me some ideas about that. Thanks

Comment: Found better answer here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580519/custom-json-serialization-for-each-item-in-ienumerable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this since it requires to pass in a DateTime Object (Let A be the single converted value and B be the container of the list of DateTimes):

```
public class DateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}


public class A
{

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<A> dates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580519/custom-json-serialization-for-each-item-in-ienumerable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  Here is the better answer