# How to format a Date into SQL server using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to storage into my database ONLY the DATE not DATE AND TIME, only Date, but it always came with the time together.

This is how I do to storage only the date inside of String :

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

And works fine, but now, I want to storage a StringDate to a Date in my SQL Server database. So I did this :

EntityTable...

```
 [Column(TypeName = "date")]
 public DateTime? InicialDate { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
InicialDate = DateTime.ParseExact("01-12-2016",
                             "dd/MM/yyyy",
                             new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

And inside of my Table, the Date is not at the right format as I expected, I came like this :

```
2017-12-01 and not, DAY-MONTH-YEAR....
```

And if I try to make a query and retrieve the date, i came like this :

```
"InicialDate": "2017-12-01T00:00:00"
```

I just want to save ONLY the DATE without time!

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is creating your Date type for using whole project. Also there is some Data class already developed: https://github.com/claycephas/csharp-date

Comment: So, do I have to change the dataType from my SQL server? is current Date!

Comment: No need, EF make conversation for your.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created the table with `[Column(TypeName = "date")]`, please check the schema and data of the table, the type of column **InicialDate** should be [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql), which doesn't save the time portion of [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql).

The time portion you saw in the result (i.e. **`T00:00:00`**) was appended by EF, when it was cast to [DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: got it, so how to remove this `T00:00:00` ?

Comment: Use [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) on the field, e.g. `InicialDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: You can also refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net), if the final result is generated by Json.NET from Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is internally just a single number (probably an int/long, representing the number of seconds since the Epoch; not sure about this, though; but it doesn't really matter here) and how it's displayed as a string depends on the format used. `DateTime.ParseExact("01-12-2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));` parses the date into DateTime internal representation according to the pt-BR rules for displaying date, then when EF is posting this to the db it converts the internal representation to ISO-8601 textual form (because SQL is text-based), then the db engine again converts it into a number form and stores it. When you look in the db, you see it as `2017-12-01`, because the tool you use to do this is set up to display dates in the ISO-8601 format.

So, the date is stored correctly, what you seed depends on the format the particular app uses to display dates.

Answer (score -2):

Change DateTime to nvarchar(10) in database if u use DateTime in database 00.00.00 will be automatically assigned by database. So, you are getting time with it while retrieving.

> Change column datatype to Varchar issue will be resolved.

Sincerely,

Thiyagu Rajendran

**Please mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark if they don't.

Comment: You can change the datatype in your sql server from datetime to varchar(10) to avoid these kinda issues.