# Avoid Ignore milliseconds when it has 0 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have following values for my Subscription StartDate and EndDate in my database.

```
StartDate = 2017-05-12 16:13:39.007 
EndDate   = 2017-10-12 10:23:28.100
```

My API Controller.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSubscription()
{

 var license = _licenseService.GetLicense(curUser.Id);
 response = Util.Create(HttpStatusCode.OK, message: "Subscription Found", data: license);
}
```

This is how my response looks in postman.

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"data": {
"licenses": [
  {
    "licenseId": 597,
    "startDate": "2017-05-12T16:13:39.007Z",
    "endDate": "2017-10-12T10:23:28.1Z" // notice 100 ms is trimmed to 1
   }
  ]}}
```

If you notice in the above response the number of characters in the date(s) are different.Because 00 part of the ms is trimmed

But this creates problem for my mobile clients because they format the date accordingly.

How do I make sure such trimming doesn't happen for any date whether the date has value like

```
2017-05-12 16:13:39.007  or 2017-05-12 16:13:39.000
```

Thanks.

Comment: what does the ending `Z` mean?

Comment: Apparently your mobile clients do not *format* date. They just accept and display whatever string they receive as string. If they actually formatted the date, it would not matter for them because 1/10 is 100/1000.

Comment: You can use [custom formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18635599/1997232) for `DateTime` or another property to serialize/deserialize `DateTime` property as string, but the question is: does it really create a problem? `20.1` seconds = `20100` ms and not `20001` ms as you claim.

Comment: @GSerg, they do but they accept a string in the below format. var date = Date(fromString:timeString, format:  .custom("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), timeZone: .utc)

Comment: @Sinatr, yes it is creating is problem. Please read my above comment to understand how

Comment: @LeiYang, UTC Time Zone