# Cannot parse DateTime with too much precision in Dart

Tags: json, dart, datetime-format

Here is my Dart code,

```
void main() {
  DateTime dt1 = DateTime.tryParse("2018-11-23T12:32:53.2928904");
  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.tryParse("2018-11-23T12:32:53.292890");
  print(dt1);  
  print(dt2);
}
```

with result,

```
null
2018-11-23 12:32:53.293
```

I'm getting a json result from a rest API which contains the DateTime value

```
"2018-11-23T12:32:53.2928904"
```

But when I try to parse it, I'm getting null. When i reduce one character at the end I'm able to parse it.
How do I parse the result to a DateTime object?
The rest API is developed with ASP.net Framework 4.5 in c#.

Comment: Look like the format is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff`, a parse exact will do . But does one even need a precision of the ten millionths of a second in a datetime value? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Since the dart DateTime.tryParse method doesn't allow you specify a format, the best ways to make ASP.NET and dart interoperate are probably:

- Customize the JSON.NET output of the API to only include 6 places of fractional seconds (see [Specifying a custom DateTime format when serializing with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net))
- Parse dates with one of the dart wrappers for moment.js on the client
- Just chop off the last digit using string manipulation - it is beyond the precision of JS date objects anyway