# CosmosDB DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery returns incorrect result for ISO formatted date string

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDB collection where I am storing ISO formatted dates as strings, for example, I have saved a document with a `start` value of `2018-07-26T09:00:00Z` and when I look in the `Data Explorer` I can see the value saved correctly.

I am using `Cosmonaut` to access my CosmosDB which exposes the `DocumentClient` and I am using `CreateDocumentQuery` to access my document but when the document gets returned from CosmosDB the `start` value is converted to a DateTime string `07/26/2018 09:00:00`

```
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("assessment-center", "ac-template-timetables");
Document document = await _cosmonautClient.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, new SqlQuerySpec
{
    QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = '713d5115-83cb-4005-abaa-25756ebc86d1'"
}, new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The above is my query, has anyone else encountered this and if so how did they resolve this problem, my expectation is that my string value should be returned as is and not interpreted as a `DateTime` which seems to be what is happening

Comment: I can't see your problem.  Do you want to store and retrieve DateTime objects?  Remember, `DateTime` is formatted as per your current culture, so 7/26/2018 is correct if you are running as a US user.

Comment: I want to store and retrieve a `string`, so when I store `2018-07-26T09:00:00Z` I expect to retrieve `2018-07-26T09:00:00Z`, the retrieved values should be `UTC` and will be passed down to a client

Comment: As I mentioned on the repo, it’s just. A serialiser setting. The solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net