# How to specify custom json converter for the generic argument of a property type

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to layer multiple JSON converters for one property because I need to specify a converter for the property's inner type that is generic.

Use case:

```
public class A {
    public Option<DateTime> Time { get; set; }
}
```

I've got an [`OptionJsonConverter`](https://gist.github.com/gmanny/dda5fe1d6ebc9dfa6843741c568a12b9) that can deserialize any `Option` and I want to specify a custom date format string for this property using the `DateFormatConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893493/579817).

Writing a custom converter would be a solution, but it's not ideal as I'll have huge code duplication.

I could use a nullable type, but I've already committed my code base to `Option`s in an effort to avoid null comparisons, and this issue may arise for other types in the future anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Converters can modify serializer's `Converters` property during `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` invocation and the new collection's contents are honored during nested serializations and deserializations.

With this, we can make a converter that temporarily adds specified converters to the `Converters` property like so:

```
public abstract class CascadeJsonConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly JsonConverter[] augmentConverters;

    protected CascadeJsonConverterBase() : this(new JsonConverter[0]) { }

    // this constructor is intended for use with JsonConverterAttribute
    protected CascadeJsonConverterBase(object[] augmentConverters)
        : this(augmentConverters.Select(FromAttributeData).ToArray())
    { }

    protected CascadeJsonConverterBase(JsonConverter[] augmentConverters)
    {
        this.augmentConverters = augmentConverters;
    }

    protected static JsonConverter FromAttributeData(object augmentConverterObj)
    {
        if (!(augmentConverterObj is object[] augmentConverter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Each augment converter data should be an object array", nameof(augmentConverters));
        }

        if (augmentConverter.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Augment converter data should include at least one item", nameof(augmentConverters));
        }

        object augmentConverterType = augmentConverter[0];
        if (!(augmentConverterType is Type convType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Augment converter data should start with its type", nameof(augmentConverters));
        }

        if (!typeof(JsonConverter).IsAssignableFrom(convType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Augment converter type should inherit from JsonConverter abstract type", nameof(augmentConverters));
        }

        object converter = Activator.CreateInstance(convType, augmentConverter.SubArray(1, augmentConverter.Length - 1));
        return (JsonConverter)converter;
    }

    protected abstract void WriteJsonInner(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer);

    protected abstract object ReadJsonInner(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (AugmentedConverterScope(serializer))
        {
            WriteJsonInner(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (AugmentedConverterScope(serializer))
        {
            return ReadJsonInner(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }

    private AugmentedConverterScopeMgr AugmentedConverterScope(JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // add augmented converters
        for (int i = augmentConverters.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            serializer.Converters.Insert(0, augmentConverters[i]);
        }

        return new AugmentedConverterScopeMgr(serializer, augmentConverters.Length);
    }

    private class AugmentedConverterScopeMgr : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly JsonSerializer serializer;
        private readonly int converterCount;

        public AugmentedConverterScopeMgr(JsonSerializer serializer, int converterCount)
        {
            this.serializer = serializer;
            this.converterCount = converterCount;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // remove augmented converters
            for (int i = 0; i < converterCount; i++)
            {
                serializer.Converters.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then create a converter that wraps another converter's logic like so:

```
public class CascadeJsonConverter : CascadeJsonConverterBase
{
    private readonly JsonConverter wrappedConverter;

    public CascadeJsonConverter(Type wrappedConverterType, object[] wrappedConvConstructorArgs, object[] augmentConverters)
        : this(CreateConverter(wrappedConverterType, wrappedConvConstructorArgs), augmentConverters.Select(FromAttributeData).ToArray())
    { }

    public CascadeJsonConverter(JsonConverter wrappedConverter, JsonConverter[] augmentConverters)
        : base(augmentConverters)
    {
        this.wrappedConverter = wrappedConverter;
    }

    private static JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type converterType, object[] convConstructorArgs)
    {
        if (!typeof(JsonConverter).IsAssignableFrom(converterType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Converter type should inherit from JsonConverter abstract type", nameof(converterType));
        }

        return (JsonConverter) Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, convConstructorArgs);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return wrappedConverter.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    protected override void WriteJsonInner(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        wrappedConverter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    protected override object ReadJsonInner(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return wrappedConverter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

which can then be used to accomplish the goal in question like so

```
public class A {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CascadeJsonConverter), // cascading converter
                   typeof(OptionJsonConverter), new object[0], // converter definition for the top-level type of the property
                   new object[] { // collection of converter definitions to use while deserializing the contents of the property
                       new object[] { typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'mm':'HH':'FF.ssK" }
                   })]
    public Option<DateTime> Time { get; set; }
}
```

With this, you can not only use different controllers for generic fields, but also in cases where a class needs to change the converter for some sub-property of a property's class. Neat :)

One caveat for this is that the top-level converter has to use the `serializer` argument in `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` methods to read and write inner values instead of using `JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<T>()` and `JToken.FromObject(x).WriteTo(writer)`. Otherwise the inner values are read and written using unconfigured serializers.

If there is a nicer way to accomplish the same task, I'd really apprecite you sharing it!