# Use JSON.net to serialize yyyyMMdd formatted date without quotes

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net

I made a dotnet core console app that serializes a custom object using Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.3.

I want to be able to serialize my custom objects DateTime property without quotes.

I'm trying to avoid making a custom JsonConverter or changing the datatype to be an int or other number types. I'm using DateFormatConverter from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893493/1440321

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyyMMdd")]
[JsonProperty("fileGenerationDate", Order = 3)]
public DateTime FileGenerationDate { get; set; }
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    ...
    "fileGenerationDate": 20180919
}
```

Current Output:

```
{
    ...
    "fileGenerationDate": "20180919"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create your own `JsonConverter` because the one that comes out-of-the-box writes values as `string` and strings are always serialized with quotes...

You can copy the code of [IsoDateTimeConverter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) and change it to write the value as an `int`.