# Serialize JSON from object to string / DateOnly

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-6.0

I have a JSON call from an object:

```
 public record SaveDate(DateOnly StartDate, string EndDate, Object[] objects);
```

```
var saveDate= new SaveDate(DateOnly.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
new Object[] { objects});
```

that when executes the API call it ends up returning

```
{
    "startDate": {
        "year": 1,
        "month": 1,
        "day": 1,
        "dayOfWeek": 1,
        "dayOfYear": 1,
        "dayNumber": 0
    },
    "endDate": "2022-07-07",
    "Object": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

however I need to have the format sent from startDate to be the same as endDate ("yyyy-MM-dd")  instead of the deserialized version. how can I do that?

note: I'm using DateOnly as type (.net 6.0) and the API expects a string in the format specified above.

Comment: What library (e.g., System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json) are you using for serialization?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json and Refit

Comment: Can you apply a custom `IsoDateTimeConverter` attribute as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: I have applied that, however I still get the object {"startDate":{"year":1,"month":1,"day":1,"dayOfWeek":1,"dayOfYear":1,"dayNumber":0},"  instead of {"startDate":{"1990-01-01"}

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2521)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` binding is not fully supported [yet](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2521). You can implement your own converter for this type:

```
public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
{
    private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public override DateOnly ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        DateOnly existingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        DateOnly.ParseExact((string)reader.Value, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public DateOnly dt { get; set; }
}

// prints {"dt":"2021-01-01"}
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass{dt = new DateOnly(2021,1,1)}));
```

For `System.Text.Json` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984245/2501279).

**UPD**

Recently released 13.0.2 version of `Newtonsoft.Json` [supports](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.2) `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly`:

> **13.0.2**
> New feature - Add support for DateOnly and TimeOnly

Comment: uhm.. I understand your logic, however I still get the deserialized object sent to the API

Comment: @Baldie47 you can [setup Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#json-content) to use needed serializer.

Answer (score 17):

For, .NET 6 I had to update Gugu Stron's answer slightly:

```cs
public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
{
    private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public override DateOnly Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateOnly.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Usage is the same:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public DateOnly dt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: reader.GetString() can be null. Are you sure it is working. It is not for me

Comment: could you please provide which packages you are using

Comment: @maxfromgermany He's using `System.Text.Json` and `System.Text.Json.Serialization`. And you're right that `reader.GetString()` can be null; you should check for that and either return an appropriate default value or throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the problem in an F# project I'm doing. So here is the F# equivalent

```ml
type DateOnlyJsonConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter<DateOnly>()
    let format = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    override this.WriteJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: DateOnly, _: JsonSerializer): unit =
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

    override this.ReadJson(reader, _, _, _, _) =
        DateOnly.ParseExact(reader.Value :?> string, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        
type TimeOnlyJsonConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter<TimeOnly>()
    let format = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"

    override this.WriteJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: TimeOnly, _: JsonSerializer): unit =
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    override this.ReadJson(reader, _, _, _, _) =
        TimeOnly.ParseExact(reader.Value :?> string, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

How to use:

```ml
type Person = {
  Name: string
  BirthDate: DateOnly
}

let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.None, DateOnlyJsonConverter())
(* result:
  { "name": "Ken", "birthDate": "1987-05-20" }
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already support for `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` for [STJ](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539) and [Newtonsoft](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/). Update your NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

Support for DateOnly and TimeOnly will be/was added in [13.0.2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2521) which is currently in [Beta 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.2-beta2). In earlier versions applications should use custom JSON converters.