# How to build a DateOnlyJsonConverter in asp.net-core 6.0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-6.0

Like many others already had the problem, I'm having problem with serializing a JSON from string/object to DateOnly.

I had already tried to implement solutions that were given in these posts.
I also use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2521

Thats my current DTO

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using JsonSerializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer;

namespace ......;

public class PostDto
{
    public PostDto(
        DateOnly postDate
    )
    {
        PostDate = postDate;
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public DateOnly PostDate { get; }
}
```

If I build the converter like this, I get the problem that `reader.Value` can be null. If I bypass the warning, which I do, I get this error.

```
public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
{
    private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    public override DateOnly ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateOnly existingValue, bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer) => DateOnly.ParseExact(((string)
        reader.Value)!, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

*System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's') at System.DateOnly.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)*

The JSON I am Posting

```
   "postDate": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 10,
      "day": 10,
      "dayOfWeek": 0
    },
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: It seems you want `DateOnly?` not `DateOnly`, and then you need to handle `null`.

Comment: what do you mean with: It seems you want `DateOnly`? not `DateOnly`,

Comment: `DateOnly?` as in `Nullable<DateOnly>`. Since you've said that the value in your JSON can be `null`, you have to do something about that in .NET. You either need to use a default value, or reflect that `null` value.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar which line of code do you mean exactly. And how exactly do I deal with it?

Comment: It was explicitly said on github, this is the solution. I wonder how it works for them.

Comment: Can you please share json which you are posting? How do you enable `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: to use this converter you should post data as `"postDate":"2020-10-10"`

Comment: And please post the corresponding controller method code. Cause this will non work for Minimal APIs - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850917/how-to-configure-newtonsoftjson-with-minimalapi-in-net-6-0/69867815#69867815)

Comment: Is there a better way to get rid of the possible nullable error?

Comment: @maxfromgermany value can be null (cause nothing prevents it from being one if somebody does not post value for it). So it is up to you how to handle this cases. You can throw an exception or provide a default value after checking if the string is null.

Answer (score 0):

To use the converter from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021064/serialize-json-from-object-to-string-dateonly/71021730#71021730) you need to post data in correct format. The this `DateOnlyJsonConverter` specifies it `"yyyy-MM-dd"` so your post body should look like:

```json
{
   "postDate": "2020-10-10"
}
```

Comment: I gues with TimeOnly it would be {"postTime": "11:11:11"}, thats right?

Comment: @maxfromgermany this converter does not handle `TimeOnly`. When implementing similar one for `TimeOnly` you can specify any format you want, but I would say that `"HH:mm:ss"` or `"HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"` looks like reasonable one.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work (for TimeOnly)

Comment: Thats shoud be the right format   `private const string TimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF"`;

Comment: It is not working

Comment: @maxfromgermany works [just fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/56X9dN)  for me.