# ASP.NET Core WebAPI - .NET 7: Swagger UI is empty, but still have HTML source

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

My project file `acc.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-acc-7EF42A0A-175F-4471-8CF7-F52B4BE2F02C</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="vy_note\**" />
    <Content Remove="vy_note\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="vy_note\**" />
    <None Remove="vy_note\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCoreRateLimit" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Marvin.Cache.Headers" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.25.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="6.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" Version="6.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OData.Core" Version="7.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="X.PagedList.Mvc.Core" Version="8.4.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="logs\" />
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

File `Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Serilog;
using System.Text;
using acc.Configurations;
using acc.Contracts;
using acc.Data;
using acc.Middleware;
using acc.Repository;
using acc.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using acc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HotelListingDbConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Acc200Context>(options => options.UseNpgsql("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=acc200;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"));
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter()); });

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApiUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApiUser>>("HotelListingApi")
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Acc200Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        b => b.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
});

builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
         new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version"),
         new HeaderApiVersionReader("X-Version"),
         new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("ver")
    );
});

builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
    options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc.WriteTo.Console().ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperConfig));

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountriesRepository, CountriesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHotelsRepository, HotelsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthManager, AuthManager>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "Bearer"
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddResponseCaching(options =>
{
    options.MaximumBodySize = 1024;
    options.UseCaseSensitivePaths = true;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
{
    options.Select().Filter().OrderBy();
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseResponseCaching();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
    context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
        new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

    await next();
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// app.MapSwagger(); // VyDN 2022_12_10. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2539

app.Run();
```

File `ServiceExtensions.cs`

```cs
using acc.Data;
using acc.Models;
using AspNetCoreRateLimit;
using Marvin.Cache.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Serilog;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace acc
{
    public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApiUser>(q => { q.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; });

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), services);
            builder.AddTokenProvider("HotelListingApi", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApiUser>));
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<Acc200Context>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }

        public static void ConfigureJWT(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
            var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY");
            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)),
                };
            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureSwaggerDoc(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      Example: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "0auth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });

        }
        public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(error =>
            {
                error.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (contextFeature != null)
                    {
                        Log.Error($"Something Went Wrong in the {contextFeature.Error}");

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(new Error
                        {
                            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                            Message = "Internal Server Error. Please Try Again Later."
                        }.ToString());
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureVersioning(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
            {
                opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
                opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                opt.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                opt.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureHttpCacheHeaders(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddResponseCaching();
            services.AddHttpCacheHeaders(
                (expirationOpt) =>
                {
                    expirationOpt.MaxAge = 120;
                    expirationOpt.CacheLocation = CacheLocation.Private;
                },
                (validationOpt) =>
                {
                    validationOpt.MustRevalidate = true;
                }
            );
        }

        public static void ConfigureAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        public static void ConfigureRateLimiting(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var rateLimitRules = new List<RateLimitRule>
            {
                new RateLimitRule
                {
                    Endpoint = "*",
                    Limit= 1,
                    Period = "5s"
                }
            };
            services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(opt =>
            {
                opt.GeneralRules = rateLimitRules;
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
            services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
        }

    }

}
```

File `DateOnlyJsonConverter.cs`

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace acc
{
    public sealed class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
    {
        public override DateOnly Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return DateOnly.FromDateTime(reader.GetDateTime());
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var isoDate = value.ToString("O");
            writer.WriteStringValue(isoDate);
        }
    }
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/72613135/3728901
```

File `appsetttings.Development.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "key": "thisisveryveryveryimportantkey",
    "Issuer": "letsprogram",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:4200/"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlServerConnStr": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=acc200;User Id=postgres; Password=postgres;"
  },
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Issuer": "acc",
    "Audience": "accClient",
    "DurationInMinutes": 10,
    "Key": "YourSuperSecretKey"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Application": "Hotel Listing API",
        "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After upgrade to .NET 7

[image]

Empty page has source `view-source:https://localhost:7283/swagger/index.html`

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <!-- Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1371 -->
    <script>
        if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
            console.log("Removing native Edge fetch in favor of swagger-ui's polyfill")
            window.fetch = undefined;
        }
    </script>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Source: https://gist.github.com/lamberta/3768814
         * Parse a string function definition and return a function object. Does not use eval.
         * @param {string} str
         * @return {function}
         *
         * Example:
         *  var f = function (x, y) { return x * y; };
         *  var g = parseFunction(f.toString());
         *  g(33, 3); //=> 99
         */
        function parseFunction(str) {
            if (!str) return void (0);

            var fn_body_idx = str.indexOf('{'),
                fn_body = str.substring(fn_body_idx + 1, str.lastIndexOf('}')),
                fn_declare = str.substring(0, fn_body_idx),
                fn_params = fn_declare.substring(fn_declare.indexOf('(') + 1, fn_declare.lastIndexOf(')')),
                args = fn_params.split(',');

            args.push(fn_body);

            function Fn() {
                return Function.apply(this, args);
            }
            Fn.prototype = Function.prototype;

            return new Fn();
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var configObject = JSON.parse('{"urls":[{"url":"v1/swagger.json","name":"acc v1"}],"deepLinking":false,"persistAuthorization":false,"displayOperationId":false,"defaultModelsExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelRendering":"example","displayRequestDuration":false,"docExpansion":"list","showExtensions":false,"showCommonExtensions":false,"supportedSubmitMethods":["get","put","post","delete","options","head","patch","trace"],"tryItOutEnabled":false}');
            var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('{"scopeSeparator":" ","scopes":[],"useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant":false,"usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant":false}');

            // Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5945
            configObject.urls.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.url.startsWith("http") || item.url.startsWith("/")) return;
                item.url = window.location.href.replace("index.html", item.url).split('#')[0];
            });

            // If validatorUrl is not explicitly provided, disable the feature by setting to null
            if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("validatorUrl"))
                configObject.validatorUrl = null

            // If oauth2RedirectUrl isn't specified, use the built-in default
            if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("oauth2RedirectUrl"))
                configObject.oauth2RedirectUrl = (new URL("oauth2-redirect.html", window.location.href)).href;

            // Apply mandatory parameters
            configObject.dom_id = "#swagger-ui";
            configObject.presets = [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset];
            configObject.layout = "StandaloneLayout";

            // Parse and add interceptor functions
            var interceptors = JSON.parse('{"RequestInterceptorFunction":null,"ResponseInterceptorFunction":null}');
            if (interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction)
                configObject.requestInterceptor = parseFunction(interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction);
            if (interceptors.ResponseInterceptorFunction)
                configObject.responseInterceptor = parseFunction(interceptors.ResponseInterceptorFunction);

            // Begin Swagger UI call region

            const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);

            ui.initOAuth(oauthConfigObject);

            // End Swagger UI call region

            window.ui = ui
        }
    </script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_vs/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="5834594221a7498a826d19cb504fd321" data-requestMappingFromServer="false" data-connectUrl="http://localhost:57705/3770e3c7e28f44539ac8f4173388863e/browserLink"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: I found the use of swagger in `Program.cs`. but where do you use `ConfigureSwaggerDoc` extension method in order to configure swagger in your project?

Comment: How to use `ConfigureSwaggerDoc` or `ServiceExtensions` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: For using swagger in your project you have to first configure it and then use it. in your `Program.cs` you have used it respectively but the configuration has been forgotten. the `ConfigureSwaggerDoc` is an extension method for `IServiceCollection`, so you can use it on `builder.Services` in `Program.cs` to configure swagger

Comment: Can you write for me few lines of code?

Comment: Upgrade source code from .NET 6 at here https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Ultimate-ASP.NET-5-Web-API-Development-Guide-/tree/main/Section%209/HotelListing.API to .NET 7. Then Swagger did not show. Maybe library does not support .NET 7 now https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tags

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the `solution`, upgrade it to `.NET 7`, restore all packages, and then run

Everything is working as well

[image]