# how to remove time part from the class object property while searlizing to json in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have created a model class and i am instantiating that class to insert data in that and then passing that class object to searlize to json.Here i am just using hardcoded date to get the json. But I am getting date like

```
"DateOfBirth":"1959-12-11T06:30:00+05:30"
```

here is my code

```
// Arrange
Driver driver = new Driver();
driver.Gender = Gender.Male;
driver.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}-01", "11-Dec-1959"));            

// Act
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(driver);

// Assert
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

also below is my class

```
public class Driver
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Can anybody suggest?

Comment: What target framework of your project? Starting from .NET 6 you can use ```DateOnly``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0

Comment: also  here is custom  DateTime serialization https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639829/7357322