# Convert asp.net date format using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

dateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["dateCreated"].ToString() --CONTROLLER

public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; } --Model

/Date(1666677654000)/ ---> *this is what I get*

I am displaying this in my HTML table using ajax method get.

Is there anyway to convert this using JavaScript?

Comment: Try this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: This looks like the `Newtonsoft.Json` format and not like asp.net date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a JS date object by using `eval`

```
var dateStr = "/Date(1666677654000)/";
var date = eval("new " + dateStr.replace(/\//g, ""));
console.log(date.toString())
```

result:

[image]

**Update**

Thanks to @JavaScript for providing another way.

```
var dateStr = "/Date(1666677654000)/";
var date = new Date(parseInt("/Date(1666677654000)/".substr(6)));
console.log(date.toString())
```

`.substr(6)`  is undefine length, so it  return the string from 6th(start) to the end of the string.

> .substr(start), start: The index of the first character to include in
> the returned substring.
>
> If length is omitted or undefined, `substr()` extracts characters to
> the end of the string.

Read [.substr(start)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr#syntax) to know more.

Comment: I would rather do `new Date(parseInt("/Date(1666677654000)/".substr(6)))` than using `eval`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. but I don't know how. Can you explain the substr(6)?